# Optimising python search code reducing execution time

Tags: python, search, networking, file-transfer

I have a block of code that I use to transfer files from my moms computer to my own computer via http.
I first indexes files on my moms system then matches them to the files present on my system and if the search fails it transfers that file to my sys.

I tested that code on small files it worked fine but I start transferring big folders it takes hell lot of more time than transferring manually over network.

I dont know what is this problem is it in my network or it is with the code

```
import requests
import client_index
import sever_index
def transfer(url):
    files = {'userfile': open(url, 'rb')}
    tim = url.rsplit('/',1)
    payload = { 'lnk' : tim[0], 'bp' : client_index.rootDir}
    r = requests.post('http://192.168.1.3/upload_file.php',files=files,data=payload,stream=True)           
    print r.text    
    return
def search(str):
    found=0
    with open("my.txt") as f:
        for line in f:

            if str==line:
                found=1
                return
        if found==0:
            print(str)
            transfer(str[:-1])
    return
c=0

with open("my.txt") as fome:
        for line in fome:
            c=c+1
if c==0:
    with open("mom.txt") as fo:
            for line in fo:  
                transfer(line[:-1])
else:
    with open("mom.txt") as fo:
        for line in fo:
            search(line)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use rsync? It does all that you need and quite fast. Regarding your problem it could be connected with you PHP environment.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening `my.txt` for each call of `search`. Whereas you should open it once. Also you should optimize search in a list of files. You are doing `O(N)` operation for each entry in `mom.txt` which gives you `O(N*M)`. With simple binary search you can do this much faster `O(M*log(N))`. Or you can make a `set` out of `my.txt` and then searching for a file will take constant time. Even more you can make sets out of both file lists and then just subtract one set out of another one.

BTW as I mentioned in comment, you should use rsync if you are working under *nix env.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Norton online backup, you can take backup for 25GB in trial version. Using this you can take backup of required files from source PC and restore it from web in your target PC. 
I find below drawbacks in using simple scripts to transfer huge files:
1. How to handle connection drops in between
2. How will you resume operation after a restart ( If you shutdown your PC for some reason )
3. For sure it will take long time, compared to Norton online backup or rsync
4. You wont have control over CPU/Memory utilization on your scripts, this may slow your PC